# First SQL to Linq Conversion

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to LINQ, can somebody guide me that how can I convert the following SQL Query in Linq.

```
Select tblIns.InsID, tblProg.ProgName 
from tblIns, tblProg 
Where tblIns.InsID = tblProg.InsID
```

I am working on MVC2 Project, I have dataContext and Reposetories , please find below the code where I need this query:

```
public IQueryable<tblInstitute> InsRepeater()
{
    return from Inst in _db.tblInstitutes 
           from Progs in _db.tblPrograms 
           Where Inst.InstituteID = Progs.InstituteID 
           Select Inst.InstituteID, Progs.ProgramName
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need is a data context which emulates your database.  Here is an example of how to do this with [linq to sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx).  You can also do it with entity framework (EF) or any other provider.

Once you have the tables created, the query then translates pretty straight forward:

```
var results = from insEntity in tablIns
              from progEntity in tablProg
              where insEntity.InsID equals progEntity.InsID
              select new { insEntity.InsID, progEntity.ProgName };
```

With the question you have asked, this is as much as I think will be useful.  In the future it's best to write questions explaining what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and then where you are stuck.  The question should be specific enough to get you just over the next hump.

---

Per your edit:  The query you have needs to have lowercase `where` and `select` and it needs to end the statement with a semi-colon (assuming it is [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)).  Then you select statement needs to select a new object.  The results would look something like this:

```
public IQueryable<tblInstitute> InsRepeater()
{
    return from Inst in _db.tblInstitutes 
           from Progs in _db.tblPrograms 
           where Inst.InstituteID equals Progs.InstituteID 
           select Inst; // for the current method header
           //select new { Inst.InstituteID, Progs.ProgramName }; // to use this one you'll have to create a new type with the properties you want to return
}
```

Comment: This type of comment should be an edit of your original post.  I will do that for you

Comment: Is that actually going to work?  Isn't your method declaration for a collection of type `tblInstitute`, but your `return` statement is returning an anonymous object that's a composition of institute and program?

Comment: only 1 error now Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' on this line (i have checked that both fields are int type of properly joined in relationship window)
   Inst.InstituteID = Progs.InstituteID

Comment: @Jawad that's because the equals operator was done incorrectly.

Comment: @NickLarsen and Jermy,  i adjusted equal operator and now error shifted to select (What could be the right form of this )       Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<DataWarehouse.tblInstitute>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Jawad, did you see @NickLarsen's update?  He changed the `select` statement, so it should work now.

Comment: yes, i didn't noticed the change, now query is working, but it is only displaying the InstituteName, is it possible to get Program names from the same query or do i have to write completely new query, sorry for keeping u busy guys but i am really very new to LINQ to SQL.

Comment: As @NickLarsen noted, you'll need to create a new type that has properties of InstitutionName, ProgramName, and anything else you need.  You can then select the results of the LINQ query into that new type and change your method declaration to return a collection of that type `IEnumerable<YourType>` or `List<YourType>`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to 
1. Create entity classes. 
2. The data context. 
3. Define relationships 
4. Query

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

```
from I in tblIns
from P in tblProg 
Where I.InsID = P.InsID
Select I.InsID, P.ProgName
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your foreign keys set up properly in the database you can just do this, there is no need to to the joins yourself:

```
from x in db.tblProgs
select x.tblIns.id, x.Progname
```